# Insert a new row and copy data validation only from a row below

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Creating a "Task List" spreadsheet where each time a task is entered in the first non-header row (row 2), it is first sorted into the rest of the already entered tasks and then a new line is added to the top (row 2) for the next entry (I'm not married to the order of operations as long as the end result is the same).

Here's a link to the spreadsheet, if needed:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1clySVeeoq1CBskDiaQywIuHZcr0zrTJIDDc1OPIc0wQ/edit?usp=sharing

I'm not familiar with writing GAS, but I am somewhat familiar enough to piece snippets together.

I've found the following bits and pieces that have almost gotten me where I want to be, but I'm either getting both data validation as well as contents or neither.  All I want is data validation with empty contents.

I've found this question asked and answered, but maybe the solutions are outdated because they're not working for me.  Or maybe I'm just doing something wrong.  Here's what I have currently...

Thank you for any assistance!

Trey

```js
function onEdit(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sh.getActiveRange().getColumnIndex();


  // Update after "Task" column is edited
  if(editedCell == 6) { 
    sh.getRange("A2:F").sort({column: 2}).sort({column: 3}).sort({column: 1});

    var firstRow = 2;
    var lCol = sh.getLastColumn();
    var range = sh.getRange(firstRow, 1, 1, lCol);
    var formulas = range.getFormulas();
    sh.insertRowsAfter(1, 1);
    newRange = sh.getRange(firstRow, 1, 1, lCol);

    var rowBelow = firstRow + 1;
    var maxCols = sh.getMaxColumns();
    var rangeToCopy = sh.getRange(rowBelow, 1, 1, maxCols);
    rangeToCopy.copyTo(sh.getRange(firstRow, 1, 1, maxCols), {validationsOnly:true});    
  }
}
```

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem with your script? And please include in your spreadsheet an example of what a successful outcome would look like.

Comment: @Tedinoz, I would like to copy a row's data validation only (the 3rd row, I would imagine would be ideal.)  The script in the OP currently copies the row with contents.  I would like for it to be blank.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be closer to what you want. But you didn't do anything with the formulas and there are no formulas in your example so that makes it difficult to figure out what you might be trying to accomplish.

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(e.range.columnStart == 6) { 
    sh.getRange("A2:I").sort({column: 2}).sort({column: 3}).sort({column: 1});//I extended this range all the way to cover the headers.  That may not be what you want.
    var range = sh.getRange(2, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn());
    var formulas = range.getFormulas();
    sh.insertRowsAfter(1, 1);
    newRange = sh.getRange(2, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn());
    var maxCols = sh.getMaxColumns();
    var rangeToCopy = sh.getRange(3, 1, 1, maxCols);
    rangeToCopy.copyTo(sh.getRange(2, 1, 1, maxCols),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_DATA_VALIDATION,false);    
  }
}
```

- [onEdit() Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

> I don't have a link for the e.range.columnStart.  I saw others using and just did a `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));` to see it for myself.  I've been using it for a long time so it must be one of those undocumented features.

Here's What it Looks Like:

> {"authMode":{},"range":{"columnStart":6,"rowStart":2,"rowEnd":2,"columnEnd":6},"source":{},"user":{"nickname":"jimesteban","email":"email@email.com"},"value":"6"}

Comment: The formulas portion was just part of one of the snippets that I didn't bother to remove.  But yes, this does exactly what I want.  One way or another, it creates a new, empty row with the data validations from below.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @Cooper Could you give me a documentation reference for `columnStart`. I've found several topics that reference it, but nothing in the Google documentation, either that, or I'm looking in the wrong place ;)

Comment: @Trey I added a comment about `e.range.columnStart` to my answer.